# Project Juypter In / Out Bracket Notation

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to learn how project Juypter works (formerly IPython Notebook)  I've very confused by the cell identifier's In[] and Out[]  I understand In = an input cell and Out = an output cell, but I'm baffled by the significance of the number within the brackets. What does that signify? It seem very prominent in the output, and I'm really baffled why I can't find any documentation on what that represents, and why it's there.  I've been searching for the past hour.

Search terms: "ipython notebook in out bracket notation indexes" and variations combinations of those words.  I've been thru numerous tutorials as well as the documentation at:
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and at 
http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html .   I'm drawing a total blank.

What does the cell notation `In[7]` and `Out[7]` signify.  Why are those numbers there?

Comment: You can also use them like In[1] or Out[1] in an expression but since the numbers aren't always the same it's not a great idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers after `In` and `Out` are the [execution counts](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/messaging.html#execution-counter-prompt-number) associated with the cells: the first cell executed gets 1, the second 2, and so on:

> Execution counter (prompt number)
>
> The kernel should have a single, monotonically increasing counter of all execution requests that are made with store_history=True. This counter is used to populate the In[n] and Out[n] prompts. The value of this counter will be returned as the execution_count field of all execute_reply and execute_input messages.