# What means the expressions in []: qnd out []: in python

Tags: python

Im starting to learn/understand some python codes and like to know what the mean of this instructions in blocks like this for example:

```
In [19]:
x = np.random.rand(15, 2)
x
Out[19]:
```

Comment: It's a command prompt from some IDE where you can test python interactively, and the result of execution of the given code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36022605/3001761?

Comment: It's the `>>>` of IPython https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html